# Got fired for fraternization. What to do now?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, human-resources, india, complaint

I had 1.5 and years of experience in a company and after a lot of struggle I got selected in a very good company which paid good.

They sent me to Singapore, and I did something stupid. I was caught fraternizing with a coworker who, unbeknownst to me, was the team lead's GF.  The team lead got very angry with me but politely said that he doesn't want me in the company. After 3 months I got fired.

Now back in my country when I look for a new job the first question is always why just leave the company in just 3 months  obviously, I don't want to give the real reason. And in many companies I interviewed after wasting my 2 weeks, I had to reject the offer since they don't offer good package and ask a lot of unnecessary and non-technical questions.

How can I overcome this interview situation? I want to leave all this behind and land a new job. Is there any way out of it?

Most companies I interviewed so far either don't have money or they have trust issue with me.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85067/discussion-on-question-by-ricky-sterling-got-fired-for-fraternization-what-to-d).

Comment: "in many companies I interviewed after wasting my 2 weeks, I had to reject the offer ..." - What does this part mean? If you are only interviewing for one company at a time, waiting 2 weeks for each one, that is probably a mistake. You don't know which offers will be to your liking.

Comment: Wait a minute. Isn't the team lead fraternizing too then?

Answer (score 7):

Personally, **I wouldn't list such a brief job experience in my resume**, as it would not be much relevant and even perhaps give a bad impression or raise questions (like it is happening to you).

Now, regarding the not landing a job, you have to keep searching. Job-hunting is not usually successful at the first tries.

I would also say that if it bothers you to be asked technical questions during interviews then you could have a problem there, as in *all interview processes I've been (both sides) there was almost always a part of technical questions*.

Now, If it is something that bothers you, and you can't get over, I suggest you **toughen up at least for the interview and "endure" those questions**. Otherwise it will be quite hard to land a job, moment in which you will not have to endure more technical questions on interviews.

Comment: Why do you say this will happen? Why do you think you need this brief experience? If you stayed longer perhaps it would have been worthy to include.

Comment: I think you are assuming many things here. That you are only worth X money because you have known Go and Jenkins for 3 months (surely you have other skills). That they will ask you how you know Go and Jenkins (probably may ask technical questions, or show them some projects you can disclose, but *how* you learned it doesn't matter much). One can always learn things on their own. In fact, I am sure that you learned Go and Jenkins mostly on your own (googling, SO, etc.) while on that company, rather than taking a course on Go.

Comment: 3 months experience at anything is not going to suddenly increase your value from $200 to $1000.

Comment: @RickySterling colourful metaphor notwithstanding - and no idea what CTC means - but if you were being paid $1000 in the job you were fired from why do you think you need that 3 months experience to win the same again? Maybe you're not applying for the right positions to be offered 20% of your expectation.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I overcome this interview situation? I want to leave all this
>   behind and land a new job. Is there any way out of it?
>
> Most companies I interviewed so far either don't have money or they
>   have trust issue with me.

You comments make it clear that (other than the short duration of your last job) none of this interview situation has anything at all to do with the reason you got fired. Instead, this is all about:

- Have two short-duration jobs in your recent work history
- Not wanting to accept a lower-paying job at a smaller company
- Not wanting to wait the 2 months or so you expect it would take to get hired by a larger company
- Your dislike for "a lot of unnecessary and non-technical questions"

If the short-duration jobs are the primary factor for your not getting hired (as you suspect), the challenge for you will be to calm the fears of potential employers that you will leave their job quickly.

You can best approach that by addressing it directly in your interviews. Tell the interviewer that you are now looking for a company where you can settle in for the long haul. Talk about your experience and your skills, how it would fit in well with the interviewer's company, and why that makes you feel like this is the king of company where you want to stay.

You may have to learn to tolerate "unnecessary and non-technical questions". Like it or not, it's just part of the interviewing game.

And if you truly feel that you cannot wait the amount of time it would take to land a job with the kind of company you prefer (2 months?) you may be better off taking short-duration temp jobs while you continue your search.

Comment: @RickySterling Lieing would be the worst thing you could do.

Answer (score -3):

According to the comment thread on the OP it seems like you misunderstand what it means to be a "girlfriend".  It seems like your superior was interested in this girl, and she was interested in you and not him, and he was jealous and got you fired because of it.  These things happen; they suck, but they happen.

In any case, I think you should just be upfront about it.  When they ask about it at an interview, just explain the situation, like "my supervisor liked a girl, she liked me and not him, and he fired me because he was jealous".  Or something like that.  This, unfortunately, happens, and any reasonable company should be understanding of that situation.

The important part is, whatever you say, you should make it known that the termination was not due to any kind of work-related cause; it was not because you were inefficient, it was not a personality conflict with your coworkers.  You're not abrasive and you're not a slacker; those are the 2 most important things that interviewers are looking for when they ask these types of questions and the most important thing is to explain that you are neither of these things.

Comment: No, you should not go into such detail. "My supervisor liked a girl, she liked me and not him..." This is not the sort of story you tell to an job interviewer.

Comment: @RickySterling Honesty is the best policy.  Try to be honest without giving away too much personal information.  If you start by lying to your prospective future employer, it will not look good on you